# How to use UTF8 in javascript

Tags: javascript, encoding

I have a code demo in lang.js:

```
var $lang = {
    todayStr1: "Hôm nay" // Vietnam
    todayStr2: "Today"   // English
}
```

When I echo $lang result is :

> H?m nay
>   Today

How to ideas for fix utf8 in JavaScript?

Comment: What environment are you using javascript in?

Comment: Use the charset attribute of the <script> tag<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/myscript.js" charset="utf-8"></script>

Answer (score 10, accepted):

you can test it when attach lang.js

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="[path]/lang.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
```